# What is the equivalent of command "Compass watch" for LESS CSS pre-processor?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, frontend, compass-sass

I was using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) as CSS pre-processor for Drupal theme. Where in the command line if I use `$ compass watch`. It keep on watching the change in .scss file and apply to .css file.

Just I am trying [Bootstrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) and there I am using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) CSS pre-processor, Where I have to use `$ lessc less/style.less css/style.css` every time to apply change.

What is the equivalent of `$ compass watch` for LESS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to install less-watch-compiler: 
   `npm install -g less-watch-compiler`
2. Make sure you installed less globally: 
   `npm install -g less`
3. In Terminal, navigate to your working directory path and run the following command: 
   `less-watch-compiler FOLDER_TO_WATCH FOLDER_TO_OUTPUT`

Comment: It is showing error, `Error: Cannot find module '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal7114/sites/all/themes/lsubtheme/less/less-watch-compiler.js'`

Comment: sorry, you need to install less-watch-compiler: `npm install -g less-watch-compiler` here is the link (https://github.com/jonycheung/deadsimple-less-watch-compiler). Also make sure to install less globally `npm install -g less`

Comment: Ok, installation worked well. But I think the Command will be `less-watch-compiler FOLDER_TO_WATCH FOLDER_TO_OUTPUT` not `node less-watch-compiler.js less css` as it is described on the github page, Could you please confirm this, and update your answer, so I will accept that as final answer.